# Como repetir uma imagem HTML CSS

Tags: html5, css3

Quero utilizar uma imagem no cabeçalho do site, ela é pequena e gostaria de repetí-la na horizontal por todo o header utilizando o CSS.

O HTML é o seguinte:

```
<body>
<header>
    <div id="cabecalho">
        <img src="pasta/imagem.jpg">
        <h1>Texto</h1>
        <h2>Texto</h2>
    </div>
</header>
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: O que você tentou?

Comment: Tentei utilizar no css o background-repeat: repeat-x. Mas não sei se chamei o seletor correto. tentei ir diretamente em img{}, depois tentei header img{}, div#cabecalho img{}, etc.

Comment: Cara, pra usar o background-repeat a imagem precisa ser definida pela propriedade `background: url('caminho');`, e não diretamente no HTML pela tag IMG.

Comment: também não funcionou Natan. Me manda um exemplo se puder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não vai conseguir repetir a imagem usando o `background-repeat: repeat-x;` porque na verdade não existe nenhum background especificado. O que você precisa é carregar a imagem que você quer através do `background-image:url(...)`. Ai sim você poderá dar instruções para ele. Exemplo:

```css
#cabecalho {
    background-image:url('http://placehold.it/30x30');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id="cabecalho">
        <h1>Texto</h1>
        <h2>Texto</h2>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Descobri que meu maior problema era a url da imagem. Utilizei o background-image e deu certo. valeu mesmo! :)

Answer (score -1):

Tente colocar:

```css
#cabecalho {
    background-image:url('http://placehold.it/30x30');
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
```